# creating a xar archive using the tar utility in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, tar

I am trying to create a xar archive using the tar utility in FreeBSD

```
tar -c -f test --format xar index.html
```

I get the following error

```
Can't use format xar: Xar not supported on this platform
```

How can I enable xar support for my FreeBSD machine?

Comment: Try using `XAR` (all caps) instead of `xar` (lower-case)?

Comment: @nomad.rc That doesn't work. I get the following error instead `Can't use format XAR: No such format 'XAR'`

Comment: The `libarchive-formats(5)` man page sections  for the formats `.cab`, `.xar`, and `.lha`  are blank entries, leading me to believe that they may not be supported by bsd tar.

Answer (score 2):

FreeBSD's `tar` doesn't support the `xar` format, but once again ports to the rescue - `archivers/xar` seems to be what you want!